# Sagemaker Pipeline Error: Failed to upload to jumpstart-cache-prod-ap-southeast-1/source-directory-tarballs/lightgbm/inference/classification

Tags: pipeline, amazon-sagemaker, lightgbm

I encountered this error when running pipeline.upsert()

```
S3UploadFailedError: Failed to upload /tmp/tmpexrxqr32/new.tar.gz to jumpstart-cache-prod-ap-southeast-1/source-directory-tarballs/lightgbm/inference/classification/v1.1.2/sourcedir.tar.gz: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied
```

My pipeline consists of preprocessing, training, evaluating, creating model and transforming step. When i ran these steps seprarately they were working just fine, but when I put them together in a pipeline, the mentioned error occured. Can anyone tell me what is the cause of this error, I did not write any line of code to upload anything to Jumpstart S3.

```
model = Model(
    image_uri=infer_image_uri,
    model_data=step_train.properties.ModelArtifacts.S3ModelArtifacts,
    sagemaker_session=pipeline_session,
    role=role,
    source_dir=infer_source_uri,
    entry_point="inference.py"
)
```

When I comment out the entry_point line, pipeline.upsert() returned no error, but the transform job failed. The model I'm using is JumpStart LightGBM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Nature of the problem

This happens by default because your experiment tries to [upload the source code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/automatic-model-tuning-ex-bucket.html) into its default bucket (which is the jumpstart bucket).

You can check the default bucket assigned to pipeline_session by printing [pipeline_session.default_bucket()](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/utility/session.html#sagemaker.session.Session.default_bucket).

Evidently you do not have the correct [write permissions on that bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_examples.html#policy_library_S3) and I encourage you to check them.

When you comment the entry_point, it doesn't give you that error precisely because it doesn't have anything to load. However, the moment it tries to do inference, it does not find the script clearly.

---

#### One possible quick and controllable solution

If you want to apply a cheat to verify what I told you, try putting the `code_location` parameter in the [Model](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/model.html).

This way you can control exactly where your pipeline step goes to write. You will clearly need to specify the s3 uri of the desired destination folder.

> **code_location** (str) – Name of the S3 bucket where custom code is
> uploaded (default: None). If not specified, the default bucket created
> by sagemaker.session.Session is used.

Comment: I checked the pipeline_session's default bucket, it is not jumpstart bucket but the sagemaker session default bucket, the format of its name is like “sagemaker-{region}-{aws-account-id}”.

Comment: Did you check the default bucket at pipeline execution? Because in order to write to the bucket that has jumpstart prefix, it has to have it as the default. Also, have you tried specifying the code_location?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I don't know how to check the default bucket at pipeline execution, so I created a variable pipeline_session, pipeline_session = sagemaker.workflow.pipeline_context.PipelineSession() and passed it to the constructor of Model object. to make sure the session is correct. I also tried setting code_location to my s3 bucket, the pipeline.upsert() can run successfully now, but the transform step failed. The log messages are quite a lot, some of them are 'NotImplementedError:' and 'Please provide a model_fn implementation'. Is this because the inference code is missing?

Comment: For the default bucket, you can simply put a print(pipeline_session.default_bucket()) anywhere in the pipeline script (e.g. above a component definition). When you upsert, you also see that print in the logs.

As for the error you say, it does indeed not find your source code. Here it depends on how you wrote the pipeline code, and I think you need to open a new question for that.

Comment: Thank you really much. I will try seeking help with the missing inference code problem.